# C# Automated Exception Handling

Tags: c#, exception

I found an automated exception/error/bug handeling/tracking software offering. It was a hosted service and it easily plugged into an existing .NET (C#) application. I thought I bookmarked it but cant find it or remember what it was. Does anyone know of such a beast? (It was not from Red-Gate)

Comment: do you mean Resharper: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/ ?

Comment: it was more like jetbrains youtrack but thats not it either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It was CodeSmith Insight.
I had to search my browser history one by one until I found it. Luckily I saw it only a month ago.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean Smartassembly ( http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/ )... it has some exception/error etc. features which are hosted...

Answer (score 1):

There is [Windows Error Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487440), from Microsoft.

Comment: Sorry, my ESP is on the blink today.